# Error: SafeProxy contract is not deployed on the current network

Tags: gnosis-safe, gnosis

I'm trying to deploy a gnosis-safe (safe-core-sdk 3.0.0) on Polygon network (chain id: 137).

I've set up `contractNetworks` below using `@gnosis.pm/safe-deployments` library.

```
  const contractNetworks: ContractNetworksConfig = {
    [chainId]: {
      multiSendAddress:
        getMultiSendDeployment()?.networkAddresses[chainId.toString()],
      multiSendCallOnlyAddress:
        getMultiSendCallOnlyDeployment()?.networkAddresses[chainId.toString()],
      safeMasterCopyAddress:
        getSafeL2SingletonDeployment()?.networkAddresses[chainId.toString()],
      safeProxyFactoryAddress:
        getProxyFactoryDeployment()?.networkAddresses[chainId.toString()],
    },
  } as ContractNetworksConfig;
```

```
    safeFactory = await SafeFactory.create({
      ethAdapter,
      contractNetworks,
    });
```

```
  const safeSdk = await safeFactory.deploySafe({
    safeAccountConfig,
    callback,
  });
```

The `callback` is being called with `txHash` successfully but the `deploysafe` method is failing with `Error: SafeProxy contract is not deployed on the current network`.

Am I missing something?